# unable to install ubuntu from usb drive

Tags: usb

i was installing windows and suddenly it showed msg that computer could install windows as it was unable to retrive some files ever since than when ever i m trying to install windows it show status 0xc000000f. since i was unable to install windows, i am trying to install ubuntu . i made a bootable flash drive using 'unetbootin' but when installing i dont get option install ubuntu and other option i only get default as a option.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you elaborate on what you've been able to do, are you able to launch Ubuntu from the USB?

Answer (score 1):

This post is about 2 months old but I'll thrown in my 2 cents anyway for others looking for answers .

For what-ever reason, the author of this post had problems installing Windows.
Whether it was a bad MBR (master boot record) , a bad Windows disk or bad area of the hard drive,  or whatever it was, there is one thing that many people are unaware of when they are trying to install an operating system from the USB.
And that is, you first need make sure your BIOS knows what type of medium you are installing from.

Is it a CD-DVD ? Is it a USB device? or is it from the internal hard drive?

When you boot up your computer, usually on the "Very very First screen, it will have on it somewhere advising you to press a key to "enter setup" or "Change boot options menu"
In either screen that shows up , here is where you direct the BIOS to either boot from a Disk , a USB device of some type, or the hard drive.
Each computer maker is different in their design of the BIOS, but basically most all computers going back about 10 years, desktop & laptop,  will have this option.

So, to boot from ANY USB device , you must first set the BIOS so it knows it will boot from that particular area or if you computer has a boot options menu you just press the key relating to the choice listed.

NOTE:
In the "Boot options menu" , (this is a screen outside the confines of the BIOS), found on many by pressing F10 orF12 ,(see your manual),  you can just choose what area to boot from for that boot only.
When you make a choice from the 
Boot options menu" screen , this will boot from that choice  Once ONLY,   Then the computer will boot from its normal setting. (what ever the BIOS has been set at)

THE BIOS:
 When you make changes to the BIOS & save the settings , it will reboot with the setting set permanent until you go in and change it again.

Answer (score 0):

The install option during boot has been removed and Ubuntu will boot up and present you with the option to either Try or Install from the GUI...  Hope this helps...